# Handling Arrays of custom objects in Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm having some issues with creating a Mongoid document that includes an *array* of custom objects.

I my particular case I intend to store an array of `BaseDevice` objects. The `BaseDevice` class is already mongified and serializes from/to a plain hash using Mongoid's [custom fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#fields) support. This works pretty well on single object.

For storing an array of `BaseDevice`, I've created the following class:

```
class BaseDeviceArray < Array
  class << self  
    def demongoize(object)
      object ? object.map{ |obj| BaseDevice.demongoize obj } : new
    end

    def evolve(object)
      case
        when BaseDeviceArray then object.mongoize
        else object
      end
    end
  end

  def mongoize
    self.map(&:mongoize)
  end
end
```

The mongoid document looks like this

```
class MongoPeriph
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :devices, type: BaseDeviceArray
end
```

Let's say `some_devices` is an array containing two `BaseDevice` instances. 
What happens is the following: when I assign `some_devices` to the devices fields of the `MongoPeriph` instance that works correctly.

```
mp = MongoPeriph.create
mp.devices = some_devices
mp.devices # => [#<BaseDevice:0x007fa84bac0080>,#<BaseDevice:0x007fa84baaff78>]
```

When try to send `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift` methods to the devices field within the mongoid document, nothing seems to happen. The changes are not appearing on the `mp` object. Also when referencing one of the objects by index (i.e. when calling `mp.devices[0].some_method`) the world does not change.

When *popping* objects from the array, on every `pop` a new object is given. This is expected as the deserializer is instantiating a new `BaseDevice` object for every `pop`, but the internal field is not updated i.e. the object stays there and one can pop endlessly.

Using the `BaseDeviceArray` separate from a mongoid document works as expected:

```
foo = BaseDeviceArray.new
foo << BaseDevice.new
```

results in an array with a BaseDevice object.

Btw. I found one other [approach](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongoid/1287rw4f78/creating-array-fields-of-specific-and-custom-types) to this on the net. It is a more generalized way of implementing what I need, but it *monkey-patches* Mongoid. Something I try to avoid. Moreover that solution seems to have the same issue my approach has.

Comment: Adding these relations resulted in `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
from`...`/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:113:in 'needs_no_database_query?'` It seems it wants me to fully "mongoize" the `BaseDevice` (and derived) class with fields etc. What I'm _trying_ to achieve is to have the plain object (in an array) embedded in a mongoid document.

Comment: I don't know exactly what qualifies an object to being able to embed it inside a document. I figured, having the de/mogoize methods present should make it a "qualified" mongo object. In the mean time I have it more or less working with the embedded relations. I forgot to add `super` to the `BaseDevice`initializer, wich threw mongoid off its track. After including `Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic` it seems to work. Anyway I would rather have the "plain" object without the all the Mongo-clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Issue in your code is that you have `#mongoize` (instance) method but you actually need `::mongoize` (class) method. You never create an instance of `BaseDeviceArray` thus instance methods are useless.

Here's an example of how I did the `::mongoize` method where I actually have in mongo a `Hash` with a single key with array value. Also I wanted to make the resulting array into a hash with ids as keys for easier lookup.

```
def demongoize(hash)
  return validate_hash(hash)["TestRecord"].each_with_object({}) do |r, m|
    rec = TestRecord.new(r)
    m[rec.case_id] = rec
  end
end

def mongoize(object)
  case object
  when Array then {"TestRecord" => object.map(&:mongoize)}
  when Hash
    if object["TestRecord"]
      # this gets actually called when doing TestRun.new(hash)
      mongoize(demongoize(object))
    else
      {"TestRecord" => object.values.map(&:mongoize)}
    end
  else raise("dunno how to convert #{object.class} into records JSON")
  end
end

def evolve(object)
  # can't see how we want to process this here yet
  # docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-documents
  object
end
```

I guess op task done long ago but thought somebody may find it useful.